# CALayer setNeedsDisplay can not work?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, calayer, nsnotificationcenter, setneedsdisplay

My class is a `CALayer` subclass, and I have added a observer through `NSNotificationCenter`, when catching the message, it will run function like this:

```
- (void)setCurrentAutoValue:(NSNotification *) obj
{

     [self setNeedsDiaplay];
}
```

but this does not work, can anyone help?

Comment: Did you really mean `setNeedsDiaplay` or perhaps `setNeedsDisplay`?

Comment: My **CALayer** must redraw all contents at once ,when the **NSNotificationCenter** post redraw message.Even though `[self setNeedsDiaplay];` had been called,any things have not changed.

Comment: Did you mean to **mis-spell** it?

Comment: You might want to have a close look at the Xcode compiler warnings. It will warn you if you've accidentally misspelled methods/functions. Note that being a dynamic language Objective-C code will still compile even it method names don't resolve (at compile time)!

Comment: Thank Jay suggestion.I have checked compiler message,and There are no warings and errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, it is necessary to call setNeedsDisplay on the main thread.  You can do this by using the `performSelectorOnMainThread` method.  For example in your case:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setNeedsDisplay) withObject:0 waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue updating my CALayers through another thread. If i called any of the following lines directly in the same thread it worked perfectly:

```
              [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
              [self needsDisplay];
              [self.circleLayer needsDisplay];
              [self.circleLayer setNeedsDisplay];
```

But when calling these through another thread, there was no change. I played around a bit and ended up using

```
              [self display];
```

which was the only thing that forced the CALayers to update. Self is an NSOpenGLView which contains several layers and sublayers. Maybe this can help. Every CALayer has the same method available. Maybe you should call display.

Comment: I have no view which contains my layers.It running in a safari NPAPI plug-in.

Comment: Maybe you could just use [self display], which is also part of CALayers. I checked my recent project. It will also lead to an update of the CALayers. - (void)setCurrentAutoValue:(NSNotification *) obj 

{
 [self display];
}
could possibly do the trick.

Comment: I found the apple Developer Documentation said [` You should not call this method directly.`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: I know about the entry in the developer doc. But maybe it is worth a try. There seems to be a problem with the update behavior of CALayers.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that i could only update a CALayer with an animation, not by setting it's content (a CGPath to the property "path"). What seems to be the only solution was removing all animations of the layer first and then set the new path:

```
[_myLayer removeAllAnimations];
UIBezierPath *newPath = ...
_myLayer.path = newPath.CGPath;
```

Answer (score 0):

Note to self: Or the frame of the CALayer was never set. Whenever there's a problem with a CALayer, first makes sure its frame != NSZeroRect.